# Alternative Proof why algebraic groups are smooth

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, modules, singularity-theory

---

### Definitions:

---

Let $k$ be a field, by an affine algebraic group we will mean an affine group scheme $G$ over $Spec(k)$ with the property that the coordinate ring of the  underlying affine scheme $|G_{\bar{k}}|:=G \otimes_k Spec(\bar{k})$ is a coordinate ring of an algebraic $\bar{k}$-group (in the classical (variety) sense).

---

### Question:

Is there something wrong with *this* proof of $|G|$'s smoothness (something is bothering me about it):

---

### The "Proof":

---

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic $k$-group and denote by $\bar{G}$ the affine scheme \ $G\times_{Spec(k)} Spec(\bar{k})$.  The universal property of the fibre product ensures that $\bar{G}$ is also an affine algebraic $\bar{k}$-group .  Moreover, the inclusion of $k$ into $\bar{k}$ ensures $\bar{k}$ is a $k$-algebra, whence there is an isomorphism of $\bar{k}[G]$-modules : \begin{equation}
\Omega_{\bar{k}[G]|\bar{k}} \cong \Omega_{k[G]|k}\otimes_{k[G]} \bar{k}[G].  
\end{equation}  From which it is deduced that: $\Omega_{\bar{k}[G]|\bar{k}}$ is $\bar{k}[G]$-free of rank $n$ if and only if $\Omega_{k[G]|k}$ is $k[G]$-free of rank $n$.  Therefore, it is enough to show the theorem for $\bar{G}$.
\item The algebraic variety  $V(\bar{k}[\bar{G}])$ \textit{(in the classical sense)} contains a non-singular point \textit{p}, hence $\Omega_{\bar{k}[\bar{G}]_{\mathscr{I}(p)}|k}$ is a free $\bar{k}[\bar{G}]_{\mathscr{I}(p)}$-module.

$\bar{G}$ is a group, therefore the left multiplication $\lambda_g$ on $\bar{G}$ is an automorphism .  Whence, for any point $p$ in $\bar{G}$, there is an isomorphism of $k$ algebras: $\psi: k[G]_g \rightarrow k[G]_x$.  This induces a short exact sequence of $k[G]_p$-modules :

\begin{equation}
\Omega_{k[G]_g|k[G]_g} \rightarrow \Omega_{k[G]_p|k[G]_g}  \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}

$\Omega_{k[G]_g|k[G]_g}$ is a free $k[G]_g$-module on no generators, hence $\Omega_{k[G]_g|k[G]_g}$ is the $0$ $k[G]_g$-module.

The exactness of the above, therefore implies that $\Omega_{k[G]_|k[G]_g}$ is also trivial and in particular it is a projective $k[G]_p$-module.

Since the point $g$ was chosen to be nonsingular, the serre-swan theorem implies $\Omega_{k[G]_g|k}$ is an $k[G]_g$-projective module; whence: $\Omega_{k[G]_p|k}$ is $k[G]_p$-projective.

Since $p$ was chosen arbitrarily and $\Omega_{k[G]_p|k}\cong (\Omega_{k[G]|k})_p$, then $\Omega_{k[G]|k}$ is locally free since; by the serre-swan theorem $\bar{G}$, is smoothness is then deduced.

Comment: If you know that over $\bar{k}$, any (reduced) algebraic group is smooth, then the general case just results from the definition of smootheness: $G$ is smooth over $k$ if $G_{\bar{k}}$ is smooth. So I don't see the point of a new proof.

Comment: I though it would be a nice application of the serre-swan theorem, (which i review just earlier in my paper).  However, yes the "classical proof" is a two-liner, but it doesn't give the same "intuitive" insight into an application of how concept of the module of Kahler forms being a projective module can be used.